# What is the best way to handle multiple run targets in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm attempting to create a Build.scala that has multiple projects/targets for the run action.  I had started trying to define it as a sub-project like:

```
val this_one = Project(
    id = "Main",
    base = file(".")
    settings = ...
)
```

My first guess is that I have the wrong settings stuff, or the config doesn't belong in a Project definition like this.

To elaborate a little, I have more than one main() I want to run in a single source tree.  There are a couple of tools that go with the main project itself, and I would like to be able to execute them selectively from the sbt console.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Do you need to start multiple subprojects when you issue `run` or what?

Comment: I have more than one main() I want to be able to run so-to-speak.  I want to run this tool, or that tool, both of which are in this source tree.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out SBT is just smart enough to figure it out by itself!  If you have multiple classes with a main(), it gives you a choice when you type "run" at the SBT prompt!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the main class using run-main. Something like:

sbt "run-main com.company.project.Main1"

sbt "run-main com.company.project.Main2"